# A splitting of an exact sequence is a connection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, connections

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over a scheme $S$ and let $\mathcal E$ be a vector bundle on $X$.

For $\mathcal P^1_{X/S}$ the sheaf of principal parts on $X$, Let $1$ be the global section on $\mathcal P^1_{X/S}$ with constant value $1$.

There is an exact sequence:

$0\to \Omega^1_{X/S}\otimes \mathcal E\to \mathcal P^1_{X/S}\otimes \mathcal E \xrightarrow[]{p} \mathcal E \to 0 $.

Let $s\in Hom(\mathcal E, \mathcal P^1_{X/S}\otimes \mathcal E)$ be a split.

> Is it true that the map $\nabla: e\to 1.e - s(e)$ is a connection?

Suppose it is true, then we shoud check the "Leibniz rule":

$\nabla(fe) = f\nabla(e) +df\otimes e \Leftrightarrow s(fe) = f.s(e) -df\otimes e$.

But I see no evidence of this last equation being verified by the split $s$ so I have a doubt regarding this question.

Thank you for your lights.

### edit

Denote by $ \mathcal I $ the quasi-coherent ideal sheaf of $ \mathcal O_X $-modules corresponding to $ \Delta: X\hookrightarrow  X\otimes_S X$, we have $\mathcal{P}_{X/S}^n:=\Delta^{*}( \mathcal{O}_{X\times_S X}) / \mathcal{I}^{n+1}$

And there is a fundamental exact sequence (that we can get by the 3rd isomorphism theorem):
$0\to \mathcal I^j/\mathcal I^{j+1} \to \mathcal P^j_{X/S}\to \mathcal P^{j-1}_{X/S} \to 0$ for all $j\ge 0$.

Taking $j=1$, we have $ 0\to \omega_{X/S} \to \mathcal P^1_{X/S}\xrightarrow[]{} \mathcal O_x \to 0$ and tensoring with $\mathcal E$ gives the exact sequence.

Comment: $e\in\mathcal{E}$ and $s(e)\in \mathcal{P}^1_{X/S}\otimes \mathcal{E}$, so what does $e-s(e)$ mean?

Comment: Thank you @Mohan for pointing that out, I made an edit to the question. now $1.e = 1\otimes e \in \mathcal P^1_{X/S}\otimes \mathcal{E}$

Comment: In my understanding, the middle term is different. Can you explain how you got your sequence and what $\mathcal{P}^1_{X/S}$ mean to you?

Comment: @Mohan please check my edit on how we get the exact sequence

Comment: The standard exact sequence comes (from my understanding) as follows. If $\Delta^2$ denote what you denote, then we have $\mathcal{P}^1_{X/S}(\mathcal{E}$ is $p2_*p_1^*\mathcal{E}$, which fits into an exact sequence $0\to \mathcal{E}\otimes \omega_{X/S}\to \mathcal{P}^1(\mathcal{E})\to \mathcal{E}\to 0$. The middle term is not $\mathcal{P}^1_{X/S}\otimes \mathcal{E}$.